# errno 5 install

Tags: permissions

I am trying to install ubuntu on my desktop.

I used a usb that I had used successfully to my laptop, but it doesn't work for desktop. (12.04 32bit)
When I am trying to boot from usb it says that no os detected in usb and only choice is to restart.

I have also burned a dvd with ubuntu 12.10 64bit but when I try to install I get an error:
[Errno 5] input/output error

However, I can use the dvd to "try" (and not install) ubuntu.

No I don't have any os in hdd. Before it was dual boot windows 7 and windows 8.

I don't know what to do! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try re-burning the ISO image on a CD at a lower speed.